# OCS will not find SQL backend database, any suggestions?

Tags: windows-server-2003, networking, ms-office-communicator

I am currently trying to install OCS 2007 R2 on a domain of VM's, no matter what i try i cannot make the OCS install wizard find the SQL database.

i have tried:-

Check ports open (checked with nmap)

Protocols Enabled

All SQL Services running including browser

DNS/AD/Group policies correctly setup

Firewall rules correct

SQL 2005 SP2 installed with BC pack

Client tools intalled on OCS machine match SQL machine

Used UDL file to check connectivity between machines

does anyone have anymore suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try a different SQL client on the OCS machine to connect to the SQL Server. I would use [QueryExpress](http://www.albahari.com/queryexpress.aspx) because it is a single file and requires no installation. Then I would sniff the network to see whether any packets go anywhere.

Comment: i have used wireshark whilst trying the discovery and running SQL queries, i cant identify any packets that suggest that the connection was refussed.